# what is the error in this code and why?

Tags: java

```
class Person {
    String name = “No name";
    public Person(String nm) { name = nm; }
}

class Employee extends Person {
   String emplD = “0000”;
   public Employee(String id) { empID = id; }
}

public class EmployeeTest {
   public static void main(String[ ] args) 
   {  
      Employee e = new Employee(”4321”);
      System.out.println(e.empID);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think there is an error? Please ask a *proper* question.

Comment: One problem I can see is the horrible indentation.

Comment: Did you edit this in a wordprocessor? Your quotes must be normal ascii quotes, `"` for string and `'` for characters. The start-quotation, end-quotation quotes are not correct.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of Employee must call its super constructor, the constructor of Person.

```
public class Person 
{
  private String name;

  public Person(String nm) 
  { 
    this.name = nm; 
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return this.name;
  }
}

public class Employee extends Person 
{
   private String emplD;

   public Employee(String nm, String id) 
   { 
     super(nm);
     this.empID = id; 
   }

   public String getId()
   {
     return this.empID;
   }
}

public class EmployeeTest 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {  
    Employee e = new Employee("Some Name", "4321");
    System.out.println(e.getID());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `“No name’` into `“No name"` (closing quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's here:

`String name = “No name’;`

should it be:

`String name = "No name";`

Also, I'm not sure if this is the editor that you've pasted it in from doing this, but this is wrong too:

`Employee e = new Employee(”4321”);`

should be:

`Employee e = new Employee("4321");`

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

`String name = “No name’;`

to:

`String name = “No name";`

check your closing qoutes.

Answer (score 1):

A number of things:

1. You're using the wrong kind of quote characters around your strings.  You need to use `"`.  Not `“`, `'`, or `”`.
2. Your `Person` class has no default constructor.  Because of this you must explicitly call `super("some name");` as the first line of your `Employee` constructor (I would suggest adding a constructor that takes both `name` and `employeeId` as parameters).
3. You declared the property as `emplD` (with a lower-case `L` character), but you try to assign to it as `empID` (with an uppercase `I` character).  You can call it whatever you want, but the name needs to match in both places.
4. Your object design violates the basic principles of encapsulation.  The `name` and `empID` properties should be private fields, and if external classes need access to these values, then you should provide the appropriate public getter methods.  In other words, instead of `e.empID` you should be able to say `e.getEmpID()`.
5. It is generally not good coding style to define multiple classes in a single file, particularly when all of them are meant to be publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Your empID field is not public / there is no accessor method for it / it is not defined as a property.  Also don't expect people to help if you provide absolutely no information on the error other than the source code and a vague post title.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the constructor of the superclass (`Person`) in the constructor of the class `Employeesuper(id); Please find the correct code below.

```
public Employee(String id) {super(id);empID =id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling a super class constructor would fix the issue !

```
    public class Person {
     String name = "No name";
     public Person(String nm) { name = nm; }
    }

    public class Employee extends Person {
    String empID = "0000";
    public Employee(String id) { 
    super("Some Name");
    empID = id; }
   }

   public class EmployeeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Employee e = new Employee("4321");
    System.out.println(e.empID);
    }
   }
```